# Why is the generated POT file from WordPress.org not adding my plugin description to the POT file?

Tags: plugins, localization

So I ran into this issue before and was able to get it fixed by using the get POT from the admin side of WordPress.org. However, with this plugin when I make the POT file it doesn't have the plugin description inside it. Any ideas why this would be happening?

The code for the plugin can be found here: https://github.com/pderksen/WP-Stripe-Checkout

You can see I added the Text Domain and Domain Path plugin headers as well.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The makepot code being used on WordPress.org is a slightly older version that we have not updated yet, specifically with this fix:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/25665

Basically, it's only looking in stripe.php for your main plugin lines, not searching for and then finding stripe-checkout.php.

This was fixed in the developer tools 7 weeks ago:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/27399

But the change has not propagated to everywhere yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Otto, I spent a lot of time on your blog trying to figure out what I was doing wrong :)